# Create emission files by my data emission for wrf-chem

Tags: wrf-chem

Does anybody here have any experience with creating my own wrfchemi outputs from the emissions that are in different format, txt, netcdf and grib for instance?

What I want to do, basically, is to use my own emissions inside the WRF/Chem model.

I have a netcdf and grib and txt of emissions of co2 and ch4 (gridded) with each grid having a value for the emissions.  I want to convert this to a readable format for the WRF/Chem.

I have read the emissions guide of the WRF/Chem, but it does not really expound on details about this especially about the following.

How to deal with the speciation (my data has co2 and ch4). Where exactly do I place this in the new emissions file (the wrfchemi) I want. There are many co2 and ch4 species there (like emi_co2, CO2FIRE, ppm, kg m**-2 s**-1).

Comment: I've created emissions files for WRF-Chem, but not for CO$_2$ or CH$_4$ exactly. I've primarily used the NEI emissions dataset for air quality. But I think a critical question that must be asked is where are you deriving your anthropogenic emissions from? You usually get the wrfchemi file from convert_emiss.exe which is produced after `./compile emi_conv` (provided there aren't any errors after you've made the necessary adjustments).

Comment: The convert_emiss.exe program takes the biogenic and anthropogenic intermediate emissions files and produces the netCDF emissions file. However, for it to work properly, you need to have the intermediate emissions files, so you need a source, such as EDGAR/RETRO (which you can follow in the emissions guide). But like I said above, I don't know how my experience carries over, as the NEI is not suggested for CO$_2$ or CH$_4$ emissions, and I struggled to make other emissions inventories work properly.

Comment: thanks for the response , but the NEI, have it's data as you have said( EDGAR/RETRO)but I have downloaded my data and they are on different format(txt, netcdf and grib) . and I want create emission files like (wrfchemi) my self without using prep_chem_sorce.